# Adding different colored bar in Column chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, column-chart

I am trying to add different colors bar but when I use `colors` in options it seems to be taking first option red for all the bars. Any help ? I am using `datatable`

Please find the code below:

```
    graphData = data;  
    var arr = Object.keys(graphData).map(function (k) { return graphData[k] });
    var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    tdata.addColumn('string', 'Testing');
    tdata.addColumn('number', 'Amount');

    var col1 = Object.keys(graphData[0])[0];
    col1 = col1.replace("_", " ");
    var col2 = Object.keys(graphData[0])[1];
    col2 = col2.replace("_", " ");
    var col3 = Object.keys(graphData[0])[2];
    col3 = col3.replace("_", " ");

    if (col3 == "TM Automation") {
        col3 = col3.replace("Auto", "T")
    }

    tdata.addRow([col1, arr[0].Manual])
    tdata.addRow([col2, arr[0].OCB_Auto]);
    tdata.addRow([col3, arr[0].Amount]);

    options = {
        fontSize: 12,
        height: 430,
        width: 380,
        chartArea: { left: "25%", top: "20%", right: "5%", bottom: "10%" },
        title: 'Project',
        pieSliceText: 'value',
        colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
        'is3D': true
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('drilldown_div'));
    chart.draw(tdata, options);
    return false;
```

Comment: I mean when I am using colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue'] all the bars are colored red. I want them to be of different colors.

Comment: Please see this example, if this is not that you want, please provide the current status as fiddle and desired result as a picture.http://jsfiddle.net/x8dafm9u/258/